# how to find the first 5 (N) sentence from the text content

Tags: php, arrays, string

i am trying to find the first 5 sentences from the description content. Please help . Thank you

Comment: Alright, can you show some effort and post the code you've tried here?

Comment: Well, how is a sentence marked? By a full stop or an exclamation mark and so on. So use php's string search functions for the 5th ocurance, accept everything before.

Comment: i have used the regular expressions but no luck. the sentenses ends with "." and may be the '?' also

Comment: Even if it doesn't work, show us what you've tried so far, so we know what to assist you with.

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in some file and when you mean sentence you mean they are separated by `\n`, following code should solve the problem.

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('head -5 testfile');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```